# ng-repeat directive sort disable when using (key, value) for multidimensional array

Tags: angularjs

I have a multidimensional array, where I keep filter name and its list.

like the example below

```
{"rel":["aa","cc","bb"],"cst":["ff","ee","gg"],"mtm":["hh","jj","ii"]}
```

"rel", "cst" and "mtm" is used as a filter name and each filter will have its own list to be displayed.

Now my problem is when I use ng-repeat in angular js, it sorts the filter in alphabetical order which I dont wanted.

So I found a workaround to solve this problem.

My Solution:

Add integer to the filter(key) like the below example

```
{"1rel":["aa","cc","bb"],"2cst":["ff","ee","gg"],"3mtm":["hh","jj","ii"]}
```

while printing the key just use a function to remove first character and then print.

```
 <script>
    angular.module('ngrepeat-sort-remove', []).controller('ngrepeat-sort', function($scope) {       

        $scope.ngtestrepeat = {"1rel":["aa","cc","bb"],"2cst":["ff","ee","gg"],"3mm":["hh","jj","ii"]};
        $scope.removenum =function(key){
            return key? key.substr(1) : '';
        };

    });

    </script>


<body ng-app="ngrepeat-sort-remove" ng-controller="ngrepeat-sort">
<div class="ngtest" ng-repeat="(key, value) in ngtestrepeat   ">    
    {{removenum(key)+'-Loop start'}}        
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="row in value">{{row}} </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</body>
```

If you want to create this more generic way you can add number with underscore and remove them using a function while display.

My angular version: v1.3.14

If anybody has a better solution to this kindly post here.

Comment: But this http://plnkr.co/edit/0F1NdEQQuDtnrAfrKDiN?p=preview example which works without prefixing numbers.

Comment: check with angular version: v1.3.14

Comment: Yeah, you are right I've update my answer for this issue hope that will be helpful. Can you please check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script>
    angular.module('ngrepeat-sort-remove', []).controller('ngrepeat-sort', function($scope) {       

        $scope.ngtestrepeat = {"rel":["aa","cc","bb"],"cst":["ff","ee","gg"],"mm":["hh","jj","ii"]};
        $scope.keyArray=Object.keys($scope.ngtestrepeat);

    });

    </script>


<body ng-app="ngrepeat-sort-remove" ng-controller="ngrepeat-sort">
<div class="ngtest" ng-repeat="key in keyArray">    
    {{key+'-Loop start'}}        
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="row in ngtestrepeat[key]">{{row}} </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: <li ng-repeat="row in ngtestrepeat.key">{{row}} </li> is empty

Comment: Not . It's [ ].           ngtestrepeat[key]

Comment: This is better for sure, because it will generate the keyArray once

Answer (score 1):

Can you check out this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zrZLr4sN8Hh1kbswWeSN?p=preview) solution with angular v 1.3.14.

In Template:

```
<div class="ngtest" ng-repeat="key in objectKeys(ngtestrepeat)" ng-init="value = values[key]">    
  {{key}}<ul><li ng-repeat="row in objectValues(ngtestrepeat[key])">{{row}}</li></ul>
</div>
```

In Controller:

```
  $scope.ngtestrepeat = {"rel":["aa","cc","bb"],"cst":["ff","ee","gg"],"mm":["hh","jj","ii"]};
  $scope.objectKeys = function(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj);
  }
  $scope.objectValues = function(obj){
    return Object.values(obj);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS versions [up to and including 1.3 sort the keys alphabetically](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties).

So to as an option you can try to [update to AngularJS 1.4+](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6210). If this is not unacceptable for you, then the recommended workaround is to convert your object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer before providing it to `ngRepeat`. Using a filter like [`toArrayFilter`](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter) can help you with this.

Example:

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  var ngtestrepeat = {"rel":["aa","cc","bb"],"cst":["ff","ee","gg"],"mm":["hh","jj","ii"]};
  
  $scope.ngtestrepeat = convertObjToArray(ngtestrepeat);
  
  function convertObjToArray (obj) {
    if (!angular.isObject(obj)) return obj;
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
        var value = obj[key];
        return angular.isObject(value) ?
          Object.defineProperty(value, '$key', { enumerable: false, value: key}) :
          { $key: key, $value: value };
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.12/angular.js" ></script>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="ngtest" ng-repeat="item in ngtestrepeat">    
      {{item.$key}}<ul><li ng-repeat="row in item">{{row}}</li></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:** Using functions in bindings like `{{removenum(key)+'-Loop start'}}` will make the function `removenum` to call on each `$digest` cycle and could make it slow in case of long arrays/heavy calculations, so this is not recommended if you care about performance.

Comment: I will upgrade for sure, I hope the next version will not break my code